# STS/Eclipse permission denied error when trying to build workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am running STS4 which is a variant of eclipse for the spring framework in conjunction with maven. I am able to build my workspace only if I run:

```
sudo mvn clean install
```

If I try to run the build from the STS IDE, I get permission denied error on multiple files.

I have tried changing permissions on the entire project folder and still get the same results.

How can I get STS to build the workspace as sudo, or what other way can I get this to work reliably from within the IDE?

EDIT: I am using Mac OS

Comment: To build the workspace as _sudo_ run STS/Eclipse as _sudo_. Does switching to a new workspace (_File > Switch Workspace_) and importing the projects from the old workspace (_File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace_) work?

Comment: @howlger Changing workspaces didn't make a difference. I ran the app from command line as sudo and the build still doesn't work and now doesn't output anything to console when trying to run build. Its strange I can't find my info on this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Probally a unix permission error, when you builded the project with super user permission (sudo), maven has created some files that have root (the super user) as the owner. Probally, you are running your STS without super user permission. So, when you try to build the project without super user permission (with your IDE, running normally), you do not have permission to replace current files (that ones that has root as the owner).